# Reactor Retry: reactor.retry.Retry vs. reactor.util.retry.Retry

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-retry

First time I use retry pattern in reactor.

I have got totally confused with the management of retrying in reactor. The main source of confusion is the existing 2 Retry classes in the same package!

I want to retry a Mono/Flux process when specific exceptions happens, during a max number of times.

My first step is create a `reactor.retry.Retry` in this way.

```
reactor.retry.Retry retry = reactor.retry.Retry
        .anyOf(
                WebClientResponseException.BadRequest.class,
                WebClientResponseException.BadGateway.class)
        .retryMax(nRetries);
```

And then, I want to parameterize my mono with

```
mymono.retryWhen(utilRetry);
```

Following the documentation in [Interface Retry](https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/retry/Retry.html) I have to convert the `reactor.retry.Retry` object in a `reactor.util.retry.Retry` using the method `withThrowable`, but there is no sample (and the sample in the doc doesn't work because the objects are not compatible).

So, I'm looking for something like

utilRetry=retry.*somemethod*()

Any comment for newbie will be welcome!

UPDATE:

I have found this issue [reactor.retry.Retry does not provide methods for Mono.retryWhen(Retry retrySpec) #231](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/issues/231) where it seems there is some migration conflics, but does not provide a canonical solution